# Hook onto Add New Category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

When a user clicks the Add New Category for my custom post type of Packages I wish to create a new page with the same name as the new category at the same time. I can create a new page through code but I cannot find the right hook for my function.php to run it.

What I need is a hook that will run for only the Packages post type.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out the `created_term` hook:

```
/**
 * Do 'stuff' when a term is created in the 'country' taxonomy 
 * using info from the referred page
 *
 * @param integer $term_id
 * @param integer $tt_id
 * @param string $taxonomy
 * @return void
 */
function custom_created_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy )
{
    $my_cpt = 'packages';  // Edit this to your needs
    $my_tax = 'category';  // Edit this to your needs

    if( DOING_AJAX && $my_tax === $taxonomy )
    {
        // Try to get the post type from the post id in the referred page url 
        // Example: /wp-admin/post.php?post=2122&action=edit&message=1

        parse_str( parse_url( wp_get_referer(), PHP_URL_QUERY ) , $params );

        if( isset( $params['post'] ) )
        {
            $post_id = intval( $params['post'] );
            if( $post_id > 0 && $my_cpt === get_post_type( $post_id ) )
            {
                // do stuff ... 

            }
        }           
    }   
}
```

The ajax request is sent to `admin-ajax.php` when you use *"+ Add New category"* to create a new category in the edit post screen. The form data sent in this ajax request, doesn't seems to contain any explicit information on the current post object. Therefore I use the referred page info as a last resort.

There might be other better ways to do this, but I'm not sure how ;-)

Comment: sorry just noticed as I was implementing this code is that actually I wish to add a page under the 'packages' custom post type when adding a category to it. Can I pass the post type the category is being added to and check that:  if( 'packages' === $posttype){

Comment: maybe the updated code will get you somewhat closer finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think using WordPress hook for custom taxonomy will be cleaner and faster.

```
do_action( "create_{$taxonomy}", int $term_id, int $tt_id )
```

As an example to fire a function when a new WooCommerce category gets created:

```
function custom_created_term( $term_id, $tt_id ) {
   // do stuff 
}
add_action('create_product_cat','custom_created_term');
```