# Update permalinks when new category added to custom post type taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy

Note: this question also appears on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060613/update-permalinks-when-new-category-added-to-custom-post-type-taxonomy (but is not getting much love).

Have created a collection of Custom Post Types (CPT) for a WordPress theme I am working on (along with their own taxonomies and tags). For the purpose of this question I will just focus on the 'projects' CPT.

When a new project category is added, and then linked to in the navigation menu - the user will see a 404 error until permalinks are saved, clearing WordPress' route caching.

I was thinking the best way to achieve this would be to use flush_rewrite_rules();

Although, saying that - I don't take it lightly as best practice strongly recommends only using this function when activating/deactivating a plugin. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage

What I want to do is hook into the action that fires when a new CPT category is created (either via the post or admin screen) and then run the flush rewrite upon that action so that the WP admin doesn't have to concern themselves with forcing Wordpress route caching via update on permalinks.

I looked at this [Hook onto Add New Category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116616/hook-onto-add-new-category) for a possible solution and attempted to use this code:

```
function custom_created_term( $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy )
{
    $project_cpt = 'CPT_PROJECT';  // Edit this to your needs
    $project_tax = 'TAX_PROJECT_CATS';  // Edit this to your needs

    if( DOING_AJAX && $project_tax === $taxonomy )
    {
        // Try to get the post type from the post id in the referred page url
        // Example: /wp-admin/post.php?post=2122&action=edit&message=1

        parse_str( parse_url( wp_get_referer(), PHP_URL_QUERY ) , $params );

        if( isset( $params['post'] ) )
        {
            $post_id = intval( $params['post'] );
            if( $post_id > 0 && $project_cpt === get_post_type( $post_id ) )
            {
                flush_rewrite_rules(true);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is not really working out for me. Not sure if I am using the right tool here or if I am doing something wrong. Have searched quite a bit to the solution but I haven't come up with a good solution to my problem here (can't find the hook for creating new CPT categories).

Comment: You don't have to flush permalinks every time you add a term to a taxonomy, only when you try to change what custom taxonomies you have, e.g. add a new taxonomy for colour, or remove one. In fact calling `flush_rewrite_rules` can slow down your site and if you call it before you register taxonomies it can break them

Comment: So we've established flush_rewrite_rules to NOT be a popular option. To make it simpler, I'd just prefer to hook into the action that is performed when a dashboard user saves changes on permalink settings. How would I do that?

Comment: You don't need to hook into permalink settings when you create a new term, no 'flushing' is required

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs It's not clear what process you're following to get these 404s. If you register the taxonomy and immediately flush rules, and then subsequent additions of new terms results in 404s, something is very wrong and broken. Without seeing your registration code it's difficult to say what that issue may be.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how custom taxonomies and post types work

This is what you do:

- On the `init` hook, call `register_custom_taxonomy` or `register_post_type`
- If you change your calls to `register_custom_taxonomy` or `register_post_type`, or add new ones in your code, regenerate permalinks by visiting the permalinks settings page and clicking save
- You're done

So if I follow the above steps and create a new taxonomy named `colour`, I do not need to flush permalinks to create `red` or `blue` terms. If I created a brand new taxonomy named `shape` I would flush the permalinks, but only once, this is so that I don't get 404's when I visit shape terms on the frontend. The same is true of custom post types

Keep in mind that `flush_rewrite_rules` is a very expensive function, and you should never need to call it. An example of when it might be called is in a plugins activation hook after it's first installed, or a WP CLI command.

### How To Avoid The 404's

Use `register_activation_hook` to flush rewrite rules. This will get called when your plugin is activated ( and only the time it's activated, not every page load ).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook

Flushing on the creation of every term is both unnecessary, and damaging

#### What If I Registered My CPT/CT In A Theme?

You can use the `after_theme_switch` hook to flush rewrite rules, however, registering post types and taxonomies in a theme is bad practice. It causes issues with data portability, e.g. if a user changes themes they loose their data.

Themes determine how a site looks, and functionality, especially data, should be defined in plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom but I'm trying to automate this process and save users the trouble to update permalinks manually as some users will not be the most technical minded if you know what I mean (the ones who dive in and fail to read instructions).

Comment: Use an activation hook for when your plugin is first installed, flushing rewrite rules every time a new term is created is an awful idea, and completely unnecessary. Nobody else does it

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out flush rewrite rules are bad again. I'm pretty sure I get it now. This is a theme plugin so it gets activated along with theme. When a user creates a new project category for the 'projects' cpt and then they go to insert that category straight into Appearance > Menu it returns an error 404. Perhaps I am missing something here but I can't really see how an activation hook that fires when first installing the plugin which actually help me.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs other people who come here might only read the answers, and I try to write self contained answers where possible so it's easier to read all in one place. With regards to themes, there are theme activation hooks too, but I would strongly advise against putting taxonomy post type registration code inside a theme as it causes data portability problems and product lock-in

Comment: I'm developing a customised solution for a very specific project, rather than a commercial theme (for use by others). It is supposed to have 'lock-in' as is heavily customised. Just want to know how to hook into the 'save permalinks' function - that's all

Comment: That's not how it works, see the update I added a few days ago about flushing when the theme is activated. If it's a bespoke piece of software then you should just flush the rules manually before handing it over to the client. If you've registered your post types and taxonomies correctly then you don't need to hook into 'save permalinks' as Core itself will generate the rules

Comment: Appreciate your help Tom, but I don't think I am communicating my problem that effectively. Ok, so scenario goes as follows... The client makes a new term in a custom taxonomy that has been setup for CPT 'publications'. Then they add that term/category straight to the Appearance > Menu. Client does not have access to Settings > Permalinks to manually flush the rules. Front end users go to the new menu item, click on it to discover it leads to an error 404 page. How would one solve this bespoke problem?

Comment: Creating a new term does not require that permalinks be flushed, are you dynamically creating new post types?

Comment: If dynamically creating new post types means allowing the site owner/admin to create new terms/categories for the custom post type - then yes I am. I just went through the process again of creating a new 'project' custom post type and then created a new project category on the fly (when creating the post). Then went to Appearance > Menu and then added in the project category. Updated the menu. Went to the front end and saw the Page 404 error. This error only goes away when I go back to Settings ? Permalinks and then update them. Has no one out there experienced this?

Comment: That isn't clear, are you talking about programmatically creating terms, aka `wp_insert_term`, or are you dynamically creating brand new custom taxonomies? It is important you be crystal clear with precise terminology so that there is no confusion. You should only need to flush permalinks once, not every time a term is created. If you get 404s for every newly created term then that is not standard or expected behaviour and you need to start disabling things to figure out what the cause is. Something has gone terribly wrong elsewhere in your code and it's interfering with the standard flow

Answer (score 0):

Ok, pretty simple solution I came up with. Just put this code below into my includes within function.php:

```
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu_item', function ()
{
    flush_rewrite_rules(true);
}, 10, 2);
```

This just hooks into the nav menu update function, so it fires every time menu is updated by admin user.

I know flush rewrite is an "expensive" function but it will only be called when the navigation menu is updated which will not be all that often.